# How Camel could handle continuous large file with Split and Aggregation without OOM

Tags: java, apache-camel

In our camel configure, we will receive file and once got file, will do split and do some convert work and aggregate the result and save into file.

```
route.split().tokenize(delimiter, eachThreadMsgNum).streaming().to("seda:rawMessages?concurrentConsumers="+mutiThreadNum).process(converter).to(publishUri)
        **.aggregate(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME_ONLY), new MyAggregationStrategy())
        .completionFromBatchConsumer()**
        .to("seda:persistResult?multipleConsumers=true&concurrentConsumers=15")
        .end();

@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    // put order together in old exchange by adding the order from new exchange
        Object newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody();
        List<Object> list = null;
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<Object>();
            list.add(newBody);
            newExchange.getIn().setBody(list);
            return newExchange;
        } else {
            list = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
            list.add(newBody);
            return oldExchange;
        }
    }

}
```

And from the camel document, it suggest we'd better use aggregate after split.
So we just aggregate by incoming file name and sent to next route.

Seems like the aggregator will build an aggregate repository which will use JVM memory to implement the aggregation.

But in our case, after we received continuous big file and each file aggregated result will be > 100M String.
So after analyze the OOM heap dump file, the AggregatedRespository will hold a very big map like:

```
file_name_1 : 120M String
file_name_2 : 140M String
file_name_3 : 130M String
...
```

And we are using G1 as GC and looks like G1 is not like big object.

After remove aggregation, the OOM is gone, and heap dump have no big object found.

But the concern is why Camel suggest to use aggregation after split? looks like it is not necessary. It looks like have no impact after we remove the aggregation part, at least the result are same. The only different is if using file name aggregation, it will pick next file, even the last persist step didn't start.

And is there any way to setup some configure to let aggregation or batchConsumer not hold so much cache to finish aggregation so that it will not need to hold the big object for such long time and cause the OOM...

Comment: any one have advice?